# recv() and recvfrom() functions not receiving data from pcap using Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, network-programming, pcap

All the ports and IP addresses in pcap file are correctly set. I have tried using recv(), recfrom() and recvmsg(). Is there any other function for receiving data in Python from a pcap file?

**Server Code**

```
from scapy.all import *
pcap=rdpcap('D:/GUI code/pack1.pcap')
send(pcap,realtime=True)
```

**Client Code**

```
import socket
localIP = "192.168.16.10"
localPort = 6006# port number can be anything it should just not be in use
bufferSize = 256
# Create a datagram socket
UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPServerSocket.bind((localIP, localPort))
print("LISTENING")
iter=0
count_in_loop=0
while (True):
    bytesAddressPair = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    print(bytesAddressPair)
```

Comment: Did you verify the packets are actually being sent out from the server's network adapter? Did you verify that the packets are arriving on the client's network adapter?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Verified that the packets are being sent and received using Wireshark as client.

Comment: Then, can you please show an example of the actual packets in question? Are the packets being sent to `192.168.16.10:6006` specifically, or at least are subnet broadcast packets? That is the only way your UDP socket will be able to receive them.